# How in Spark to set default value if column has NULL?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am tring to join 2 DataFrames in Spark Framework.

```
val final = mf1.join(mf2,mf1("KEY")===mf2("MOBILE_KEY"), "left").select(
        mf1("*"),
        mf2("MOBILE_TYPE")
    )
)
```

Next code works but return `null` value in `MOBILE_TYPE` column to some records.
How set default value if column has null value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
val final = mf1.join(mf2,mf1("KEY")===mf2("MOBILE_KEY"), "left").select(
        mf1("*"),
        mf2("MOBILE_TYPE")
    )
).withColumn("MOBILE_TYPE",when(col("MOBILE_TYPE").isNull,"DEFAULT_VALUE").otherwise(col("MOBILE_TYPE")))
```

`withColumn` and `when` API can work.